# How to use a "return" as a macro in a ternary operation?

Tags: c++, macros

I have a c++ code as below:

```
#define xxx return

int main()
{
    xxx 0;
}
```

It works as expected.

Now I change the code like this:

```
#define xxx return
#define TEST(X) ((X) == (false) ? (xxx 1) : ())

int main()
{
    bool b = false;
    TEST(b);
    return 0;
}
```

In a word, I want to `return 1` if `b` is `false`. But I get the error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
```

Comment: Forget the macro for a minute. Just try `(b == false ? return 1 : ())` and you'll see that it doesn't work. Once you get something that *does* work, then you can obfuscate it with a macro.

Comment: Your `TEST` macro is a ternary expression and would result in something like `b == false ? return 1 : ()` which is not allowed. Why not just define your macro as `if (x == false) xxx 1`

Comment: Note that having jump statements hidden in macros is very bad design. You might want to reconsider your approach.

Comment: Why would you ever want to write such a dirty macro? This is a "XY problem", what's the actual problem you are trying to solve with this macro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return` is a statement, and not an expression. And all three operands of `?:` must be expressions only. The `return` keyword can't appear in any of them, expanded from a macro or not.

A macro that would work in your specific example would be a simple

```
#define TEST(X) if((X) == (false)) xxx 1
```

Though, if you mess around with macros be wary of the [dangling else problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros) and proof the above against it.

Comment: Bare if statements in macros are problematic. Macro should be wrapped at least in `do { ... } while(0)`.

Comment: @user694733 Those who have the good habit of always using {} after every single if statements don't have such bugs. And need not worry about hacks so as do-while(0). This is why the requirement of always using do-while(0) for macros was dropped in MISRA-C, since they already require that you always use compound statements, making do-while(0) not only superfluous, but actively harmful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a return statement inside the ternary operator. You need to use an ordinary if.

```
#define TEST(X) if ((X)  == false) return 1;
```

Comment: Bare if statements in macros are problematic. Macro should be wrapped at least in `do { ... } while(0)`.